# PHP File Download From Ajax with a URL Redirect

Tags: php, ajax, url-rewriting, download

I'm trying to figure out how this is posssible.

I want the user to be able to click on a link, and it will download a certain file. The file will be determined in an Ajax call (right now I just have a hard coded value).

Here's my situation though: When Ajax is called, the link given for the request is part of my framework which has a front controller and the url gets redirected. Thus, I can't just send the link to a file named like download.php and have just header code in there. It goes through the whole framework process, and eventually gets to the method that handles the Ajax call.

Here's my code:

```
$('.jobApplicationDownload').click(function() {
var that = $(this);
$
.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    url : "myfw/businessHome/applications/downloadJobApplicationItem",
    data : {
        "ajaxFileType" : that.attr("data-ftype"), "ajaxApplicationId" : that.attr("data-did")
    },
    success : function(html) {
        alert(html);
    },
    error : function(XMLHttpRequest,
            textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```

});

And here's the PHP. Remember this is after going through a Front Controller and a bunch of other methods. This is by no means the first stop after the Ajax call.

```
function downloadJobApplicationItem() {
    //download.php
    //content type
    $fileName = "/myfw/common/jobs/resumes/eZACKe_1359081853_Week Three Sprints & Hurdles Workout 24th - 28th of Sept (1).pdf";
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    //read from server and write to buffer
    readfile('/myfw/common/jobs/resumes/eZACKe_1359081853_Week Three Sprints & Hurdles Workout 24th - 28th of Sept (1).pdf');
    echo $_POST['ajaxFileType']. " ". $_POST['ajaxApplicationId'];
}
```

**EDIT:** Oh, and by the way, the result of this is the stuff I'm echoing being alerted, and no file download starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm confused when reading your question because I think you are getting mixed up between multiple questions.

1. **Does the AJAX request reach the right handler?**: the URL routing mechanism used in your framework and almost every other only matters here, and it doesn't affect whether you can reach your physical file. It's an entirely different matter. Regardless, I'd say your AJAX call is correct because the echo gets alerted
2. **How to send the path to a file via AJAX call that gets redirected?**: One trick you can consider using, which is similar to what you did, is to have a central download function as AJAX handler AND construct the path to the file using parameters sent with AJAX.
3. **Why doesn't readfile output the desired file to the buffer**: it's most likely that your path is incorrect or incompatible with server setting. It'd help if you could post your server configuration here.

And posting the name of your framework doesn't hurt either :)

Comment: Well I am actually reaching the handler now and the path was incorrect. That is fixed. Now when I do readFile and get rid of the echo that is followed it, the contents of my file get alerted. This is telling me it's not picking up the header being changed. I want it to start the download immediately. And just a 'framework' I cooked up myself.

Comment: Yeah because AJAX only returns text responses. A work around could be copying your file to some temporary folder and return the absolute path to that file through AJAX and tweak your framework to allow this kind of (temporary) direct access.

A more elegant approach is instead of using ajax, just use an anchor link, and right after serving the file, terminate your script with `exit` so that browser won't get redirected and it gives an asynchronous impression.

Comment: Just to be clear, my redirect is an .htaccess url redirect/rewrite. This occurs before you get any to any code. So for you more elegant solution, how am I to serve the file and call exit before getting redirected?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this problem by buffering all the output and allowing the controllers to change or unset the redirect location. After all the controllers run, check the redirect location and write the redirect header (if necessary) at that time. Then output your buffer.

Something like this:

```
$appSettings = new AppSettings();
$appSettings->setRedirect(...);
$controller=new Controller($appSettings);
ob_start();
$controller->run(); //Your controller can call $appSettings->setRedirect(false);
$redirect=$appSettings->getRedirect();
if($redirect===false)
{
    ob_end_flush(); //Send the buffer
}
else
{
    ob_end_clean(); //Discard the buffer
    header('Location: '.$redirect);
}
```

Comment: Could you show code please? I'm having trouble following what you're saying.